# How can I set a Layout that I created to an HorizontalScrollView I extended?

Tags: android, layout, android-scrollview

I created a Layout of view's that I want to put in MyHorizontalScrollView object  that I extends from HorizontalScrollView.

Is there a way to do it?
Should I do it in another way?

If the question is unclear write a comment, thanks.

**The layout I want to put in my ScrollView object:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The class Is not realy Importent, I didn't put anything special there yet. my problem is the idea of how to do it.

Comment: Can you post the HorizontalScrollView that you've created? And where you want to put it? on a xml?

Comment: I edited it and added the code and abit of explaination